# Create custom module without bean to show up in menu

Tags: sugarcrm

I am wondering how to create custom module in SugarCRM and show link into the menu bar. So my custom module will not be a Bean, but needs to be visible in menu bar.

My `manifest.php` file is as follows:

```
$manifest = array(
    'acceptable_sugar_versions' => array(
        "rege_matches" => array("5.1.*")
    ),
    'acceptable_sugar_flavors' => array(
        'CE'
    ),
    'name' => 'CustomModule',
    'version' => '1.0',
    'description' => 'CustomModule for SugarCRM',
    'author' => 'Community',
    'published_date' => '2015/02/17',
    'type' => 'module',
    'icon' => 'icons/default/icon_CustomModule.gif',
    'is_uninstallable' => 'true',
);

$installdefs = array(
    'id'=> 'CustomModule',
    'copy' => array (
        array (
            'from' => '<basepath>/package/CustomModule',
            'to' => 'modules/CustomModule',
        ),
    ),
    'language' => array(
        array(
            'language'=> 'en_us',
            'from'=> '<basepath>/package/language/application/en_us.lang.php',
            'to_module' => 'application',
            'language' => 'en_us',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your package contains? What do you want to be in the menu bar if not a set of List/Create menu options for a new module?

Comment: In menu i need link to `index.php?module=CustomModule`. Custom Module `controller.php` will dispatch this link.